# Loop gives correct output if script run in steps but not when skript runs from scratch

Tags: python, numpy

My script contains a while loop:

```
import numpy as np


ptf = 200 #profiltiefe
dz = 5
DsD0 = 0.02
D0 = 0.16 #cm2/sec bei 20°C
Ds= D0 * DsD0 
eps= 0.3
R= 8.314 
Ptot=101300 
Te = 20
dt = 120 

modellzeit = 86400*3 
J=modellzeit/dt 
PiA = 0.04 
CA = PiA*1000/Ptot 

respannual = 10 #t C ha-1 a-1

respmol = respannual/12*10**6/10000/(365*24)
respvol_SI = respmol * R * (Te+273)/(Ptot*3600) 
respvol = respvol_SI * 100 


I= ptf/dz 
S = np.zeros(40)

for i in range(40):
    if i <= 4:
        S[i] = respvol/(2*4*dz)
    if i > 4 and i <= 8:
        S[i] = respvol/(4*4*dz)
    if i > 8 and i <= 16:
        S[i] = respvol/(8*4*dz)


Calt = np.repeat(CA,len(range(int(I+1))))
Cakt = Calt.copy()

res_out = range(1,int(J),1)

Cresult = np.array(Cakt)
faktor = dt*Ds/(dz*dz*eps) 

timestep=0
#%%
while timestep <= J:

    timestep = timestep+1

    for ii in range(int(I)):

        if ii == 0:
            s1 = Calt[ii+1]
            s2 = -3 * Calt[ii]
            s3 = 2 * CA

        elif ii == int(I-1):
            s1 = 0
            s2 = -1 * Calt[ii]
            s3 = Calt[ii-1]

        else:
            s1 = Calt[ii+1]
            s2 = -2 * Calt[ii]
            s3 = Calt[ii-1]


        result = Calt[ii]+S[ii]*dt/eps+faktor*(s1+s2+s3)
        print(result)
        Cakt[ii] = result

    Cresult = np.vstack([Cresult,Cakt])    

    Calt = Cakt.copy()
```

What is intersting: If I run the complete script print(result) gives me different (and incorrect) values. But if I add all my constants before and run the loop part of the code (shown above) the loop performs well and delivers the output I want.

Any idea why this might happen?

I am on Python 2.7.5 / Mac OS X 10.9.1/ Spyder 2.

Comment: can you correct indentation levels?

Comment: Done! Sorry for that!

Comment: @BenjaminMewes Seems like your constants are not constant at all, i.e. something modifies them in the meantime.

Comment: Can you paste the complete script (if it is not too large)? If large, please paste the usage of constants atleast.

Comment: posted the total script - Thank's for your help!

Comment: this is why `immutability` is important for deterministic behavior of even simple programs

Comment: So basically if i run the first half of the script and then the second half of the script, the while-loop delivers what I want it to do. But if I let the complete script run it doesn't compute the way I want it to do.

Comment: You are using python 2.7.5, so division of integers gives integer results.  I suspect that is not what you want.  For example, the term `respannual/12` will be 0, so `respmol` is 0.  Either change your constants to floating point values (e.g. `respannual = 10.0`), or add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script.

Comment: In that case, I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python 2.7.5, so division of integers gives integer results. I suspect that is not what you want. For example, the term `respannual/12` will be 0, so `respmol` is 0. Either change your constants to floating point values (e.g. `respannual = 10.0`), or add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script.